# Progress Bar is not dismissed

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I don't accomplish to dismiss progress bar in my Android App.
I declare an object bar object and get a String calling the doInProgress function and pass to it an object called v1. 
When the async task finishes his task, why progress bar (wichs appears) is not dismissed as declared in onPostExecute method?

In my activity I call:

```
ProgressDialog pDialog;
response = new GetString(SecondActivity.this).execute(v1).get();
```

and this is myAsync Task:

```
package com.gms;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;


public class GetString extends AsyncTask<VariablesTable, Void, String> {

        private Context context;

        public ProgressDialog pDialog;

        public GetString(Context c){
            context = c;
        }           

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }


        protected void onPostExecute() {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            if (pDialog.isShowing()){
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(VariablesTable... obj) {
            // Making HTTP request
            InputStream is = null;

            try {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(obj[0].cat, "utf-8");
                    obj[0].url += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(obj[0].url);

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();          

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return sb.toString();
        }
    }
```

Suggestions??
Thanks in advance

Comment: i think ur async task doesnt wrk ok. And onPostExecute is not calle

Comment: Question is: you know why onPostExecute is not called?

Comment: try changing onPostExecute() to onPostExecute(String resp)

Comment: @FrankBr I am facing the same issue ..Have you got any solution

Comment: Below there's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chck post execute, i doubt it works

try changing onPostExecute() to onPostExecute(String resp)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you start your ASyncTask.

```
response = new GetString(SecondActivity.this).execute(v1).get();
```

If you are calling that from the UI thread, it will make it block there. Remove the `.get()` part so the thread can continue running and execute your `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` function properly.

Comment: I use get() to get the string response by GetString Class. I'll try to set a global variable instead.

Comment: either global or do what you need with that string in the onPostExecute... this still runs on the UI thread.

Comment: I removed get() but to get progress dialog dismissed I need to touch the screen. But I would want it was dismissed automatically.

Comment: And you are sure that postExecute function gets executed ? Does the logcat show any warning of any kind at that time?

Comment: if you followed the other answers (setCancellable to true), that's what it would do, by pressing the back key or tapping on the screen, you would be able to get rid of that progress bar, but the task is still going on in the background... and it does not really solve your problem of the dismiss() call not working...

Comment: No, no Logcat messages unluckly.

Answer (score 0):

do a System.out in onPostExecute() method to check whether the control is reaching in this method or not. If onPost gets executed and dialog is not dismissing, then dismiss the dialog in a UI thread --- context.runOnUiThread and if still it doesnt work make the ProgressDialog static(not a solution just a try) and hopefully it will dismiss now.